# Database - create relationship indexes after already having string as primary keys

Tags: database, postgresql

So, here's my situation:

I'm parsing a 150GB text files database.

And that data have to be inserted in a new relational database (PostgreSQL).

And a lot of that data defines relationships (one-to-one, many-to-many etc).

Well... and those relationships will be defined while parsing the files.

IF I have to keep tracking of numerical indexes to use as primary keys, in certain situations I'll have to query the database to know what is the primary key for a specific record (and use as foreign key).

And... considering that some of those tables maybe have more than 15 million records not yet indexed (I'm inserting while creating relationships), it'll be a nightmare of time processing.

So, I'm wondering if:

1 - is that ok to use strings as primary key? It'll solve the problem of querying a large database to infer the foreign keys in the momment of parsing the files.

2 - after inserting all the database, is there any automatic or easy way to make PostgreSQL create all the relationships creating numerical indexes overriding the string primary/foreign keys?

Sorry for the long post.

And maybe I'm asking too much :)

Thanks!
Gio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - This is a polemic topic. But I'd like to advice you to not use strings on primary keys if possible. It can drive you to less efficient queries, index bloat and others annoying problems. IMHO Surrogate keys works well in most cases.

2 - No. You'll have to create a column and populate - probably - with `row_number`, drop old PK cascaded, create new PK, create new FK and so on. Not a hard work, but somewhat tedious.

I don't have much info about your dataset, some problems with data quality can happen? E.g.: Relationship failure (child row pointing to a nonexistent parent).

Anyway you can store most frequent data in a cache. Use Redis, Memcache or just a key-valued type available in the programming language that you're using. You'll query database just while cache is warming-up. But not forget to define a cache invalidation strategy otherwise you can overload your memory.

Comment: Ok, I'm gonna follow your suggestions. Thank you very much! Anyway, no, there's no chance of orphan child rows. The dataset is extremely well formed in that sense.

Comment: @GilcanMachado Glad to help you. Could you accept the answer?